# Hide Swift documentation in Xcode help viewer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, documentation, xcode6

When I browse online iOS docs for classes, it has an option to show `swift`, `obj-c`, or `both`. I have mine currently set on `obj-c` (I peek at Swift from time to time, but in my day to day work, it just clutters the docs).

Is there a way to do similar in the integrate help viewer for Xcode 6? Every time I browse a class document, I have to mentally filter out all of the `swift` variants.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the wonderful [Dash documentation browser](http://kapeli.com/dash). It has the possibility to turn on/off swift, objective-c, ...

Comment: I used to know how to filter the docs by language, but can't find it in recent versions Xcode. Where is that setting?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is just a set of HTML files. If it's downloaded, you can edit a CSS file to completely hide Swift or Objective-C code.

1. Open Documentation window.
2. Select "Editor" > "Share" > "Open in Browser" menu.
3. Copy the corresponding part of the address of the page that opens up:

`/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.XXX.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/`

4. Switch to Finder, and use "Go" > "Go to Folder" menu to open up the folder.
5. Browse to `Resources/XXXX/CSS` folder and edit "xcode5.css" file. You should add either of these blocks to hide Swift or Objective-C:

   div .Swift {
       display: none !important;
   }

   div .Objective-C {
       display: none !important;
   }
6. Restart Xcode and enjoy reduced clutter.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks. Why this is not a switch in Xcode is anyone's guess. Not ready to try Swift now and this trick keeps the visual noise out of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to choose `Editor -> Share -> Open in Browser`. You can also make a shortcut via `Preferences... -> Key Bindings` or the Keyboard System Preferences.

It still opens Safari, but it is just one step, so it might be a good solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to the bottom of those folder trees, located the files specified (one for iOS docs, one for Mac OS X docs), duplicated each file for a backup (command D in Finder), opened each file and pasted :

> div .Swift {
>
> display: none !important;
>
> }

at the end of each file.

Rock and Roll!  Thank you pointum, you made my day.

Ref: My file path was like this. Note that your path may differ by the number just before the /CSS/

> Mac OS X Documentation File (yours may differ by the 1058)
>   ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.OSX.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Resources/1058/CSS/xcode5.css
>
> iOS Documentation File (yours may differ by the 1081)
>   ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Resources/1081/CSS/xcode5.css